# Defining operator overload on pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

Given

```
struct foo {
    struct node {
        int data;
        node* next, prev;
    };
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const foo::node& n) {
         os << n.data;  
         return os;
    }
    // friend node* operator++ (list::node* n) { return n->next; }
};
```

I need to overload `++` that acts on `foo::node*` only.  Where and how do I define that operator?  My commented-out line above indicates what I'm trying to do.  Thanks.

An example usage is:

```
for (list::node* it = f.begin();  it != f.end();  ++it)
     std::cout << *it << ' ';
```

where `f` is a `foo` object, and the `begin()` and `end()` functions return some `foo::node` pointers.

Comment: You can't define operator overloads if only primitive types are involved.

Comment: You need to make an iterator class for this. You can't just use a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ doesn't allow you to define *operator overloads* for primitive types. In this case, `foo::node*` is  primitive type.

What you can do is create your own wrapper around `foo::node*` which behaves as you desire:

```
struct node_iterator
{
    foo::node* _p;

    // ...

    friend node_iterator operator++(node_iterator n) 
    { 
        return {n._p->next}; 
    }
};
```

Comment: But how do I forward declare `foo::node` if I'm to define within the `foo` class `using iterator = node_iterator;` ?